# 0x Protocol API - Polygon (Mumbai)

Tags: polygon, 0x

The 0x Protocol API Endpoint for Polygon (Mumbai) doesn't seem to work.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://mumbai.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=0xcB1e72786A6eb3b44C2a2429e317c8a2462CFeb1&sellToken=0x9c3C9283D3e44854697Cd22D3Faa240Cfb032889&sellAmount=10000' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"query":"query {\n  pairs {\n    id\n    tokenA\n    tokenB\n    exchange\n    router\n  }\n}","variables":{}}'
```

Response

```
{
   "reason": "Server Error"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the contracts have been deployed on Mumbai but the API endpoint for that chain has not been released yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first answer, the API endpoint has been deployed so you can use it now!

But for the pair you're querying its seems that there is not enough liquidity, you can use the [the response from Joao Campos in this thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/134645/how-to-resolve-insufficient-asset-liquidity-in-0x-on-polygon-mumbai-testnet) to help you for the rest